# How Write message if no data to display in chart in the qlikview file

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

Please if I have chart when I selected filter I have no data to display how can I write an error message instead of no data to display
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello what I did is I make a text object and I put condition in the chart if the content is null, My Error message is appear.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

In the `General` tab of the chart properties there is a button saying `Error messages`. In there you can put messages on specific errors or have one for all.

Comment: I tried before, it doesn't work there is no error's name: no data to display